# EFCore OnDelete Cascade many to one

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a data model that is along the lines of:

```
public class Entity1
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Entity1 RelatedEntity { get; set; }
}
```

In my case there can be many `Entity2s` for each `Entity1` but as far as I can tell it doesn't really make sense in my data mode to have `Entity1` track all the `Entity2s` which use it. Maybe I am misunderstanding how data models are supposed to be built.

It seems (from the Microsoft tutorials) that in order to set up `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);` you need to have a 2-way link between entities. Does anyone know if it is possible to do it such that if `Entity1` is deleted it will take all `Entity2` instances with it also? Will I have to change my data model such that `Entity1` stores a list of `Entity2's`?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to make changes in Database side to enable Cascade Delete. Once you delete from EF side, it automatically deletes from other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the navigation properties is required.

All you need in order to configure a relationship is a *correct* pair of `Has{One|Many}` + `With{One|Many}`. By correct I mean the following - if the corresponding relationship end has navigation, it must be passed as argument, otherwise no lambda expression/property name should be passed).

i.e. in you case, you could use either

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity2>()
    .HasOne(e2 => e2.RelatedEntity)
    .WithMany() // no navigation property
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>()
    .WithMany<Entity2>() // no navigation property
    .HasOne(e2 => e2.RelatedEntity)
```

These are equivalent, use one or the another, neither both (to avoid conflicting configurations / discrepancies - after all, the relationship is just one, even though there are two ends).

Once you do that, you have access to relationship APIs for configuring the FK, cascade delete etc., e.g.

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
```

You could also make the FK required (which by default will turn cascade delete on):

```
.IsRequired()
```

For more info, see the [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) section of the EF Core documentation, in particular [Manual configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration)
 and [Single navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1).

Comment: This sorted it, thank you very much. Annoyingly I'd been doing the right thing just not applying the migration...